# Java String spit using regex with single forward slash not followed by a slash

Tags: java, regex, split

I want to split the URL by a forward slash, not by two forward slash.

http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/

I want to split above URL as http://www.eclipse.org, swt, snippets.

Code:

```
url = http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/;
String[] truncUrl = url.split("/");
```

Please guide me with regex.

Thanks,

Comment: you probably don't need a regex for that. Any url parser can tell you what the protocol is, and what the host is. (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html)

Comment: You forgot to add your code

Comment: Thanks. I do not want host, I just want to truncate URL for second path.

Comment: try showing us with code what you want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a combination of a negative lookbehind (that is, "not preceded by") and a negative lookahead (that is, "not followed by").  So you'll split on any `/` that's not preceded by a `/` and not followed by a `/`.

According to [the Javadoc for Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) -

- a negative lookbehind is delimited by `(?<!` and `)`
- a negative lookahead is delimited by `(?!` and `)`

So the regular expression you want is `(?<!/)/(?!/)`

Answer (score 0):

As an additional answer,

you may use this expression `((?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.&?=%#+:-]+)`

Example:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016377/java-string-spit-using-regex-with-single-forward-slash-not-followed-by-a-slash";
        Pattern rgx = Pattern.compile("((?:http(s)?://)?[\\w.&?=%#+:-]+)");
        Matcher m = rgx.matcher(url);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (m.find())
            list.add(m.group(1));

        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
https://stackoverflow.com
questions
51016377
java-string-spit-using-regex-with-single-forward-slash-not-followed-by-a-slash
```